# Connecting a backbone localstorage based app to StackMob remote server via the Stackmob Sdk

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, stackmob

I'm building which is a variation of this todos example
http://jasongiedymin.github.com/backbone-todojs-coffeescript/docs/coffeescript/todos.html

As you can see, the app saves the data to the browser's localstorage.

I want it to save it to the remote server I'm using, which is StackMob.
Having read the StackMob JS - SDK tutorial, it seems to tell me how to build an application from scratch based on the JS SDk
http://www.stackmob.com/devcenter/docs/JS-SDK-Tutorial

The question, is can I use what I already have written, and make it store the data at stackmob instead of the LocalStorage, Or I should better rewrite the app following the JS-SDK tutorial?

Thanks,
Oz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with coffeescript syntax (at least, not yet!), but I'll familiarize myself with it in the near future.  Unfortunately, the Local Storage adapter link in that Todo tutorial is broken, so I can't look into that, but in the meantime, maybe I can reason it out.  I did notice that Todo is extending from Backbone.Model via the syntax, :

```
class Todo extends Backbone.Model
```

Non-coffeescript syntax would have it laid out as:

```
var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({ ...});
```

Similarly, creating a Todo that saves to StackMob looks like:

```
var Todo = StackMob.Model.extend({...});
```

So perhaps this translation would work?

```
class Todo extends StackMob.Model

class TodoList extends StackMob.Collection
```

That seems like the coffeescript equivalent of defining a StackMob-enabled model, giving your model server-side CRUD abilities.

Models extending StackMob.Model will make an ajax call to StackMob with the JSON when calling `save()`, saving it to the server-side database.  Similarly `model.fetch()` will retrieve from the database and populate the model.

TodoList would have StackMob queries built in so you can do something like:

```
(regular JS syntax:)
//Get the first five "done" Todo items, order by the "created date"
var q = (new StackMob.Collection.Query()).equals('done', true).
    setRange(0,4).orderAsc('createddate');
var todos = new TodoList();
todos.query(q);
```

When I have more time, I will try that out myself later this week, but I wanted to get back to you now despite it being late tonight in case this can help get you going.  Don't forget, for those to actually save properly, you'll need a StackMob account and initialize the JS SDK properly.  But, the initialization steps are documented in the [Getting Started: The JS SDK](https://stackmob.com/platform/help/tutorials/html5_js_sdk) and the [JS SDK Tutorial](http://www.stackmob.com/devcenter/docs/JS-SDK-Tutorial#a-sdk_setup) docs.

Hope this gets you on your way!

Erick

Comment: sure! Just as an addendum, StackMob.Model extends Backbone.Model, and StackMob.Collection extends Backbone.Collection, so you should get everything else that you normally get with Backbone.